How do I apply a weight to an icon
I'm trying to add weight to an icon so it becomes more bold like this website explains: https://m3.material.io/styles/icons/applying-icons#d7f45762-67ac-473d-95b0-9214c791e242
However, this doesn't seem to compile - the .weight modifier isn't available.  What am I doing wrong?
Icon(
    imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Check,
    contentDescription = null,
    modifier = Modifier
        .weight(700F)
)


Compose doesn't support Material Symbols at the moment.
You could, however, use this workaround.

Go to Google Icons where u can customize the weight, grade and optical size of the icons.
After the required customization, select the icon and download the SVG.
Go to SVG To Compose Image Vector
Upload the SVG and download the generated file.

Edit: If the above method doesn't work, try using this plugin
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18619-svg-to-compose

This hasn't worked for me.  The generated .kt file doesn't show the icon.
